# Vb.net 2010, how to use two filters at the same time

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter

i want to filter a datagridview in visual basic using two columns at one time. for ex: i want to filter subject column and last name column,

im currently using this code:
me.studentbindingsource.filter = "Subject_code like '%" & ComboBox1.Text & "%'"

but it only filter one at a time.

Comment: what is the use of '{0}**' in  filter=String.Format("Subject_code like '{0}**' and Last_name like '{1}*'",Combobox1.text,strLastname)

it filter two columns and how could i filter three or more, what should i change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String.Format,

me.studentbindingsource.filter = String.Format("Subject_code like '{0}**' and Last_name like '{1}*'",Combobox1.text,strLastname)

Comment: thank you so much, it really works. :D   
by the way, what is the purpose of '{0}** while the other is '{1}*