# Filtering Bindingsource using 2 textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, filter

Im using Visual Studio 10, programming in VB, using an Oracle Database.
I need to do a filter on a DataGridView with 2 variables. The code so far looks like this:

```
TableBindingSource1.Filter = "[FIELD1] = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

How can I insert the FIELD2 and Textbox2 in this example, making both filters working together? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `filter = String.Format("Field1 = '{0}*' And Field2 = '{1}*'", var1, var2)` then `myBindSource.Filter = filter`.  No need for `DataGridView1.Refresh()` - it doesnt do what you think it does

Comment: Plutonix, thank you very much. But it resulted in "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Filter' accepts this number of arguments." Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
Me.BindingSource.Filter = "FIELD1= '" & txt1.Text & "' AND FIELD2 >= " & txt2.Text
```

'example

```
       ' Get a DataView of the table contained in the dataset.

  Dim tables As DataTableCollection = set1.Tables
  Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))

' Create a DataGridView control and add it to the form.

  Dim datagridview1 As New DataGridView()
  datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
  Me.Controls.Add(datagridview1)

' Create a BindingSource and set its DataSource property to
' the DataView.
  Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
  source1.DataSource = view1

' Set the data source for the DataGridView.
datagridview1.DataSource = source1

' The Filter string can include Boolean expressions.
source1.Filter = "artist = 'Dave Matthews' OR cd = 'Tigerlily'"
```

[Source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356973/vb-net-bindingsource-filter-two-column-conversion-not-valid)

[Source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104889/vb-net-2010-how-to-use-two-filters-at-the-same-time)

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks dejan87, but doesnt work...the result in gridview are not working with 2 variables.

Comment: @glup what message you get? I update my answer, may help you

Comment: @glup then your condition does not return any result, 
instead of 'AND' put 'OR'

Comment: Actually im testing with data that my grid is showing. And when i apply the filter, nothing changes.

Comment: @glup DataGridView1.Refresh()

Comment: i think i figure out my problem, it was in other piece of the code. I just made a little change in your solution "AND FIELD2 >=" to "AND FIELD2 =", know i think its working. I Appreciate everyone that has commented.